# JW Player fullscreen - controls not working on mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, video, jwplayer

I made my video that plays in the background without sound or controls. Here's the jwplayer code for it. It's embedded in php.

```
<div id="video"></div>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   jwplayer("video").setup({
      "playlist": "https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/media/<?php echo $url; ?>",
      "height": 560,
      "width": "100%",
      "autostart": "true",
      "mute": "true",
      "controls": "false",
      "repeat": "true",
      "stretching": "fill",
      "logo": {
         "file": "fullicon.svg",
         "hide": "true",
      },
   });
});
</script>
```

I added a logo to the video as you can see. The logo is a clickable link that's suppose to make the video full screen. I modeled the full screen some what after this page on the jwplayer's website, tweaking it for my needs. https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/using-the-browsers-new-html5-fullscreen-capabilities/

This is the code that makes the video full screen:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var $logo = $('div.jw-logo');
    if ($logo.length) {
        $logo.click(function(e) {
           var element = document.getElementById('video');
           if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
              element.mozRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
              jwplayer("video").setControls(true);
           } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
              element.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
              jwplayer("video").setControls(true);
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Everything seems to work correctly - video goes full screen, sound is playing, controls show up. The only thing wrong is when I click on any of the controls of the video, nothing happened. The controls don't work. I can use my keyboard and tab through the controls on the video player, but that's about it.

Now I did have to use `jwplayer("video").setControls(true);` to get the controls to show in full screen mode. Wonder if that has something to do with it?

Any ideas on how to get the mouse to work on the controls?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! This might help someone in the future. Had to use the document instead of the element to make it full screen.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
     var $logo = $('div.jw-logo');
     if ($logo.length) {
          $logo.click(function(e) {
               // Open full screen
               if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
                    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
               } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
                    document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
               } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                    document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
               } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                    document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
               }
          });
      }
});
```